# Logrank test for trend (proportional hazards)

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, logrank-test

How one can create a logrank test for trend and does it differ from normal logrank test? Any suggestions or literature? Maybe some R examples and functions?

Comment: Could you elaborate your hypothesis, e.g. by a formula?

Comment: To add to that it is important to state what type of variable you wish to associate with time-to-event.  If it is an unordered categorical variable then the logrank test as it was originally proposed is a decent choice.  There is no reason not to use its generalization the Cox PH model though.  And don't fall for the commonly used "tests for trend" in which a continuous variable is split into quantile groups and the quantile group integers are treated as linear in the log hazard.  This is a poorly fitting model if there ever was one.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell, I will remember not to do this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `comp` from [`survMisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survMisc/survMisc.pdf) package. It extends the `survival` package. It counts statistic and p-value for logrank test, as well as for Gehan-Breslow, Tarone-Ware, Peto-Peto and Fleming-Harrington tests and tests for trend (for all of the above mentioned). The example taken from the manual is the following:

```
data(larynx, package="KMsurv")
s4 <- survfit(Surv(time, delta) ~ stage, data=larynx)
comp(s4)
comp(s4)$tests$trendTests # outputs only the results for trend tests
```

If you compare the results with

```
survdiff(Surv(time, delta) ~ stage, data=larynx)
```

you get the same result for 'traditional' logrank test (not the trend test).

Comment: please edit yout question with a link to a vignette

Comment: I meant the manual, not the vignette.

Comment: Have you noticed that the p-values from this package are in relations `p1=1-p2` of standard SAS output? Where p1 is p-value from R package, and p2 is p-value from SAS?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that. And sometimes the results are slightly different then these obtained from SAS.

Comment: That's quite funny ins't it?

Comment: It is, maybe sth isn't done correctly and someone should report it to the authors?

Comment: Maybe should we first read their documentation about that?

Comment: Oh yeah, probably that's cleverer.

Comment: `comp` doesn't seen to work with objects of class `survfit`... I guess you wanted to say `ten(Surv(time, delta) ~ stage, data=larynx)`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, so not sure if this is what you are looking for. To test the proportional hazards assumption you can use the [Grambsch-Therneau test](http://ww.escarela.com/archivo/anahuac/03o/coxdiag.pdf) on Schoenfeld residuals of the proportional hazards model. This essentially tests the slope of  (scaled) residuals as a function of follow-up time.